# Как можно объединить все th в thead?

Tags: html, css

Есть таблица такого вида:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Грузы по Украине</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Как можно объединить все `th` в `thead`, чтобы надпись *"Грузы по Украине"* заняла все `th`, которые пустые?

Comment: `<th colspan="5"></th>`

Comment: Можете превратить комментарий в ответ, чтобы я принял его?!

Answer (score 3):

```
<th colspan="4"></th>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/byy9s/

```css
table tr th,
table tr td{    
    border: 1px solid #ccc;    
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
     <tr>
       <th colspan="4">Грузы по Украине</th>                     
     </tr>
 </thead>
 <tfoot>
    <tr>
       <td>1 </td>
       <td>1 </td>
       <td>1 </td>
       <td>1 </td>       
    </tr>
 </tfoot>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1 </td>
       <td>1 </td>
       <td>1 </td>
       <td>1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>1 </td>
       <td>1 </td>
       <td>1 </td>
       <td>1 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```